# web site as application in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, wiki

I am working with ScrewTurn Wiki. It is pre-complied Version. So When I am tring to run on IIS as Application under my pet website than it gives error like The type or namespace name 'AddressInfo' could not be found. But When I am run it as website than it works fine. Where I am doing mistake any reference to be add or thing i missed.

```
public class ProfileCommon : System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase 
 { public virtual AddressInfo BillingAddress 
        { get { return ((AddressInfo)(this.GetPropertyValue("BillingAddress")));
```

Comment: in witch dll this AddressInfo is ? maybe you forget to include it ?

Comment: public class ProfileCommon : System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase {
    
     public virtual AddressInfo BillingAddress {
         get {
            return ((AddressInfo)(this.GetPropertyValue("BillingAddress")));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have published the WIKI and placed under my website. Now in iis 7, I have made web application for WIKI under my website. It is working fine. But Web.config of WIKI is given error, for resolving I have changed with disable sessionState configuration and added

```
<clear/>
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```

under httpModules.

Now it works as sub folder of my website.